# How to change bits inside Short

Tags: c#, .net, bit, short

I have a short-variable in C# and want to change a specific bit. How can I do it the easiest way?

Comment: Perhaps show the code of your short variable?

Comment: i want to write a function, which manipulates the bit with the index x inside a short and returns the modified short

Comment: Post up your code and we can help you further

Answer (score 6):

Do you mean something like this?

```
public static short SetBit(short input, int bit)
{
    return (short) (input | (1 << bit));
}

public static short ClearBit(short input, int bit)
{
    return (short) (input & ~(1 << bit));
}
```

You could even make them extension methods if you want to.

Comment: If you wanted to do it from a boolean input, you could add a method `SetBit(short input, int bit, bool value) { return value ? SetBit(input, bit) : ClearBit(input, bit); }`

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at bitwise operators:

```
short i = 4;
short k = 1;
Console.WriteLine(i | k); //should write 5
```

You can see a list of the operators under the `Logical (boolean and bitwise)` section [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Also, did some poking around and found [this bitwise helper class](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12919/C-Bitwise-Helper-Class).  Might be worth checking out depending on your needs.